# different output trying to execute same java code

Tags: java, swing

i am using net beans 7 ide and java 6 to develop my java projects. i used the following coding to read value from serial port :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

  static CommPortIdentifier portId;
  static Enumeration portList;

  InputStream inputStream;
  SerialPort serialPort;
  Thread readThread;

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "portList :"+portList.hasMoreElements()); 
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
      portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
      if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
       if (portId.getName().equals("COM3")) {
      //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
        SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
      }
    }
  }
}

public SimpleRead() {
  try {
    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
  } catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}
  try {
    inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
  } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
  try {
    serialPort.addEventListener(this);
  } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}
  serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
  try {
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
      SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
      SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
      SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
  } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}
  readThread = new Thread(this);
  readThread.start();
}

public void run() {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
  switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
    break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

    try {
      while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
        int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
      }
      System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
    } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    break;
  }
}
}
```

When i execute from netbeans, JOptionPane showing "portList : true"
but when i double click on the jar file and tried to run, JOptionPane showing " portList : false"

Why there is different output trying to execute same java code

Comment: Why have you shown so much code when it looks to me as if only the first two lines of `main` are really relevant?

Comment: I would bet it has something to do with permissions...

Comment: Please answer any questions asked, and make comments or inquiries on any statements made in comments.  We cannot solve this by magic, we need hard facts.  As an aside, somebody thought that was a great comment?  Astonishing..

Comment: codings in manifest file  Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_32-b05 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/comm.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: sensorcount.SimpleRead

Comment: i copied and put the javax.comm.properties in jrehome/lib folder. now it is working fine.